# Why is Cauchy's integral formula always written with the function as the subject?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, soft-question

Scouring textbooks, lecture notes, Wikipedia, etc., I notice that the standard presentation of **Cauchy's integral formula** is $$f(w)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_L\frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,\mathrm dz\tag1$$ rather than $$\int_L\frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i f(w).\tag2$$

I'm new to complex analysis, and have so far directly utilised only form $(2)$ (that is, that equation as an *integral* formula<sup>҂</sup>), which, to boot, is a little more compact and reads more intuitively than form $(1).$

Or is the canonical form $(1)$ *actually* more natural? Please shed light on its intuitive interpretation that I must be missing.

<sup>҂</sup>A [formula](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/25352/372) is typically a rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variable(s), so the circle-area formula being *canonically* presented as $$r=\sqrt{\frac A\pi}$$ would similarly cause a double take: is this a quirky misnomer, is $r$ more fundamental than $A$ when discussing circles, does this square-root form lend itself better to typical applications of the equation, etc.?

Comment: I don't think that this question is particularly valuable, or helpful to others, and seems almost off topic. Lots of famous formulas are written in some sort of "cannonical form" with no real reason, and can be rewritten however you like.

Comment: @TomOldfield But the canonical form above *isn't* arbitrary in this case (see Yoni's answer). Anyway Yoni's answer made a lot of sense to me, although I see how my question might be perceived as esoteric to someone seasoned to (or totally unfamiliar with) complex analysis.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad answer, and I don't think that the question's esoteric. To me the question read as "why do we write it in this form and not the other" rather than "how can we interpret this form of the formula intuitively". I still think that the form is arbitrary since both forms have valid intuitive interpretations. That's just my opinion though, and I think that the question is only on the borderline in terms of closing. No hard feelings!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the focus of the formula is not that you can evaluate certain integrals by plugging in function values, but that you can recover a function's values by an integral along a circle.

Comment: Oh thanks- exactly the answer I needed to hear! So the *consequences* of Cauchy's integral formula matters a great deal more than the simple-minded use of it to evaluate integrals then. That explains it.

Comment: This example does also illustrate the in-fact-asymmetry of "equality": here, $A=B$ asserts something about $A$. :)

Comment: Do you have a reference or citation for this answer, or is this just an expression of your own personal opinion?

Comment: @paulgarrett: I am curious how you came to this 2013 answer.

Comment: @user1046533, some random chain of links on this site... dunno. Probably couldn't reproduce it. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: Your comment reminds me there are many cases where $X\le Y$ is preferable to $Y\ge X$ for some quantities $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @user1046533, yes, that kind of thing. We read left to right, etc. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: I recall that Terry Tao wrote something about such writing before. One may write "Let $x$ be such that $x\le \pi$" but it is very awkward to write "Let $x$ be such that $\pi \ge x$. Maybe it's a bit different in Hebrew.